# Using recollindex update for backup files

Tags: recoll

I was starting with inotify to monitor changes in my directories and launch a backup script using rclone. So I thought that, taking advantage of the fact that I'm using Recoll in my debian, I could use the changes that Recoll detected to launch rclone, without having inotify working.

I haven't been able to find in Recoll a clear log file that tells me the last files that have been modified or created, every time I update the index. I've been trying the [recoll_status](https://github.com/nbeaver/recoll_status) script, or trying to read xapiandb using xapian-delve, but without success.

Any idea how to get a list of the last added or updated documents in the Recoll index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `recollindex` to check for changes to files is an interesting idea,
but it shouldn't be necessary if I am understanding your use-case.
Rclone already looks at file size and modification time
to decide what to update:

> Normally rclone will look at modification time and size of files to see if
> they are equal. If you set this flag then rclone will check the file hash and
> size to determine if files are equal.

https://rclone.org/docs/

This is essentially the same thing that `recollindex` does.

> Use mtime instead of ctime to test if a file has been modified. The time is
> used in addition to the size, which is always used.

https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/usermanual/webhelp/docs/RCL.INSTALL.CONFIG.RECOLLCONF.TERMS.html

Take a look at the source code here for details:

```
// File signature and up to date check. The sig is based on
// m/ctime and size and the possibly new value is checked against
// the stored one.
```

https://framagit.org/medoc92/recoll/-/blob/d8edbcbc55cf7658af025212b7f01acd293d7884/src/index/fsindexer.cpp#L651

So `rclone` is doing essentially the same comparison as `recollindex`,
except instead of updating the index, `rclone` updates the remote backup.
You can just run `rclone` the same way you are currently running `recollindex`.

Furthermore, using recoll's index to decide what needs backing up
would have a number of drawbacks, such as:

- Depending on the `skippedNames` entry in `~/.recoll/recoll.conf`,
  recollindex will skip indexing many files such as PNG and JPEG files.
  Presumably you will want these files backed up.
- The index does not reflect the current state of the filesystem;
  in fact, the filesystem most likely changed while `recollindex` was running.
  So the index cannot be used as a reliable way to decide what needs updating.

By the way, when started in real time monitoring mode
recoll isn't doing anything special to detect changes;
it's using [Inotify or FAM/GAMIN](http://noah.org/wiki/Inotify,_FAM,_Gamin)
behind the scenes.
Here's a link to the relevant part of the source code if you're curious:

https://framagit.org/medoc92/recoll/-/blob/ef1b8343fad5ef1b04714a3031b207bee458ca40/src/index/rclmonprc.cpp

https://framagit.org/medoc92/recoll/-/blob/ef1b8343fad5ef1b04714a3031b207bee458ca40/src/index/rclmonrcv.cpp

The `recoll_status.py` script just polls `~/.recoll/idxstatus.txt`.
This won't have the full list of changed files, either;
it just shows what file is currently being indexed,
and only updates occasionally, not for every single file.

```
// Update the status file. Avoid doing it too often. Always do
// it at the end (status DONE)
```

https://framagit.org/medoc92/recoll/-/blob/d8edbcbc55cf7658af025212b7f01acd293d7884/src/index/recollindex.cpp#L122